# read with history

Tags: bash, command-history, readline

How can I make the builtin `read` command support history, by pressing the up/down key to cycle through them?

I've tried catching when you press the up key, however it doesn't seem to work with `read`:

```
read -p '> ' -n 3 foo
echo
echo -n "$foo" | hexdump
```

Pressing the arrow keys seems to work and I can detect it using this, however if I press <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>, it will fail as it will only read the first character of the identifier of the up-arrow, while the third is needed to distinguish the different arrow keys.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`rlwrap`](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/#rlwrap) for this, if you don't mind installing software.

You'll probably want to keep a separate history file that only maintains history for the particular prompt in your script (ie. avoid mixing with the user's shell command history).

Here's an example that might work for you:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Save in rlwrap_example.sh

HISTORY=$HOME/.myscript_history
USERINPUT=$(rlwrap -H $HISTORY sh -c 'read REPLY && echo $REPLY')
echo "User said $USERINPUT"
```

```
$ ./rlwrap_example.sh
hello
User said hello
```

In the above script, the user can use all [GNU readline](http://www.gnu.org/software/readline/) functionality, with history served from — and stored in — `~/.myscript_history`. Tweak as needed.

Alternatively, you can use bash's `read -e`, which enables readline for `read` invocations, but you will probably find its history functionality too limited (ie. almost nonexistent).

Answer (score 19):

To copy Mike Stroyan's great answer from this [old mailing list post](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2007-09/msg00004.html):

> You can use "history -r" to read a file into the shell's history
>   and "history -s" to add each line that you read into the history.
>   Then use history -w to save the history back to the file.  Here is
>   an example with vi style readline editing.

```
#!/bin/bash
history -r script_history
set -o vi
CMD=""
while true
do
    echo "Type something"
    read -e CMD
    history -s "$CMD"
    echo "You typed $CMD"
    case "$CMD" in
        stop)
            break
            ;;
        history)
            history
            ;;
    esac
done
history -w script_history
echo stopping
```

Comment: I like this solution better than `rlwrap` as (at least on my machine) `rlwrap` is unable to handle CTRL-C gracefully, e.g. try running `USERINPUT=$(rlwrap -o cat)` and pressing CTRL-C and see how your terminal behaves afterwards (run the `reset` command to return to a sane state again).

Comment: This works really nicely if you don't want to install additional libs and you are happy using a separate file to manage input.